# Are there API available to measure the flexipage loading time?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, api, performance, usagemetrics

There is "Lightning Usage App" and there is "pages" tab, we can view the flexipage performance on that app. But is there any API available for developer to access those performance data instead of using the visualized way to view it in the Lightning Usage App? We want to get the loading time of those flexipage and use the data in our own report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_lightning_usagebypagemetrics.htm) and take a look at the EPT metrics (Experienced Page Time) for your page.

Comment: Thank you so I can do a query to the LightningUsageByFlexiPageMetrics and then use SumEPT/RecordCountEPT to get the average EPT for my flexipage and generate the report. Thank you!